# Zend Framework on Vista

Tags: zend-framework, windows-vista

I am moving my first steps with the Zend Framework. I have it on my Linux partition and it works fine. Now, I want to use it on Vista. I have downloaded and installed Zend Server CE. Seems to work.

However, when I try to edit some file inside my Apache htdocs directory, surprise: I have no permissions! I have found out that - despite the fact that I am administrator - the whole Programs folder is read-only! I tried to change this, but without success: it puts it back to read-only as soon as it has finished. What can I do? It is not possible to work like this...

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try-

1) Run your text editor as an administrator before editing files.

2) Reinstall ZSCE outside of your Programs folder.

Comment: Thanks!!! I think I will try the second one. However, all this sounds pretty crazy to me. It is MY computer... GRRRRRR